# Deleting and re-attaching an image to same ActiveRecord model with Carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, carrierwave

We have a class, user, with a Carrierwave avatar, the presence of which is necessary but insufficient to trigger a callback:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ... various other stuff

  before_update :do_stuff, if: :avatar_changed_and_stuff?

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def avatar_changed_and_stuff?
    # Check if any of a number of conditions has just been met, 
    # including avatar just having been added
  end
end
```

In testing, this has been causing me quite a headache. The way I would *like* to do it is

1. Build a user object with all #ac&s conditions met
2. For each condition, make it false, then make it true, and check #do_stuff happens

For most of the other conditions, this just means setting an attribute to nil, then back to whatever it was. But because Carrierwave overwrites the 'avatar' attribute, I can't just do `user.update(avatar: nil)`.

Instead, following the Readme, I've removed it with

```
user.remove_avatar!

user.save
```

The trouble is, when in the same test I now try and re-attach a file exactly as I did in the test preparation[1], it doesn't work - `user.avatar.file` is still `nil`.

I spent a while trawling through the Carrierwave gem's source, but haven't been able to find a reason for this behaviour. In the end I hacked around it by simply generating a new instance of the record...

```
user_x = User.find user.id
```

... and then continuing the tests on the new object. This works, but a) it's frustrating that I can't figure out why, b) it's hideously ugly. Is there a better approach?

[1] Ie this way:

```
let(:image) { File.new('path/to/img.jpg') }

# Then in the test...

user.update(avatar: image)
```

Comment: Have you tried `user.reload` before testing `user.avatar.file` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that but it doesn't work :\